# Cannot autowire UserDetailsService in GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, autowired, spring-java-config

I'm getting the `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A UserDetailsService must be set` when trying to autowire custom UserDetailsService implementation in my SecurityConfig Java Config class. Here is the overview of my configuration classes.

Root config

```
@Configuration
@Import(value = { SecurityConfig.class, ServiceConfig.class })
public class RootConfig
{

}
```

ServiceConfig

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(value = "basepackage.service")
// this package includes the custom UserDetailsService implementation
// annotated by @Service
public class ServiceConfig
{

}
```

SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration
{
    // this service is injected using setter injection, omitted for clarity
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void registerGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
    throws Exception
    {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is: sometimes (but only sometimes - it seems completely random) the custom UserDetailsService is not autowired before the instantiation of `methodSecurityInterceptor` and I get the `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodSecurityInterceptor' defined in class basepackage.SecurityConfig...` and the stack ends at

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A UserDetailsService must be set
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.doAfterPropertiesSet(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:94)
```

As I mentioned previously, the `UserDetailsService` implementation is annotated with the `@Service` annotation and should be instantiated by the `ServiceConfig` in the right order. This problem happens only from time to time when deploying the app. Usually everything is instantiated correctly. When I create the `UserDetailsService` bean inside the `SecurityConfig` using `@Bean` annotation everything is fine. But I prefer keeping the services beans separated from the `SecurityConfig`. I tried experimenting with the `@Order` annotation, without success though.

Any ideas why this happens? Also, why it happens randomly and not each time? Why Spring cannot instantiate the beans in the right order? I would appreciate your help.

Comment: @Karthikeyan You obviously did not read my question... I wouldn't be asking about such simple thing.

Answer (score 2):

I was dealing with the exact same issue.  An interesting thing was that it only happens in Java 8; if I drop down to Java 7, the problem goes away. I started using some of the LocalDate stuff from java 8 though, so that's no longer an option.

Anyway, I didn't wind up being able to autowire it in and I did want my services to stay together so instead of autowiring it in, I just provided it to the AuthenticationManagerBuilder (I added a constructor to my CustomUserDetailsService). Then you can keep your services in your services package. Of course, you wouldn't annotate it as a service at that point, which may defeat your whole purpose being that it kind of works around spring but I thought I'd post the option anyway.

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal( AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth ) throws Exception
{
    auth
        .userDetailsService( new CustomUserDetailsService() )
        .passwordEncoder( passwordEncoder() );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's a very strange behavior, It happened to me a while ago. Sometimes It would just work, other times It would break with messages of "Bean of name 'UserDetailsService' must be set to DaoAuthenticationProvider" or something on those lines. I got It fixed by adding the @Autowired annotation on the constructor of my config Class.

```
@Autowired
public WebSecurityConfig(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService){
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
}
```

Applying the annotation on a setter didn't work, anyway very strange behavior.

Comment: It worked for me, i was dealing with this bug for almost 1 day, the **@Autowired** annotation doesn't work on a setter but it does in a property.

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with the same issue.
As a workaround, I've annotated `@Resource` the `UserDetailsService` (looks like the `@Resource` dependencies are injected before the `@Autowired` one)

Answer (score 1):

Yea, this has to be a bug. Overriding doAfterPropertiesSet() with some dummy logic in my custom auth provider prevents the error.  Setting a breakpoing in that override method, it's apparent that while UserDetailsService is initially null, it does get set immediately after.

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationDaoProvider extends DaoAuthenticationProvider
...

@Override
    protected void doAfterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        if(super.getUserDetailsService() != null){
            System.out.println("UserDetailsService has been configured properly");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This solved my case of `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A UserDetailsService must be set`.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this question while looking for a similar problem.
In case if this helps someone,

Solution that worked for me:

```
@Override
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider());
        }

    @Bean
        public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() throws Exception {
            DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
            authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
            authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());
            return authProvider;
        }
```

I had to create a DaoAuthenticationProvider(or any custom subclass of it) and set the injected userDetailsService as above.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue when I had an unused property as below inside my class extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
 @Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
```

Removing that solved my problem.