# A UserDetailsService must be set Error in Spring Boot app

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have 2 classes

SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
private UserDetailServiceImpl   customUserDetailsService;


@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
}
```

}

and UserDetailsServiceImpl

```
@Service
public class UserDetailServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
@Autowired
private UserRepository repository;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User currentUser = repository.findByUsername(username);

    UserDetails user = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
            username,
            currentUser.getPassword(),
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(currentUser.getRole()));
    return user;
}
```

}

Error from logs:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A UserDetailsService must be set
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.doAfterPropertiesSet(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:100)
```

From docs the error can be from this:

```
 Throws:IllegalArgumentException - if a null value was passed either as a parameter or as an element in the GrantedAuthority collection
```

Properties set not properly maybe ...
So how to set UserDetailsService ? How to fix this error ?  This example was taken from the book but it can be too old and something changed. I am pretty new to Spring.

Comment: First of all you should be programming to interfaces not concrete classes. Instead of `UserDetailsServiceImpl` use `UserDetailsService` and add `@Autowired` to get it injected.

Answer (score 4):

So I was able to fix this using the following:

For the SecurityConfig.java:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private UserDetailServiceImpl customUserDetailsService;

    //Spring injecting for you, IoC
    public SecurityConfig(UserDetailServiceImpl customUserDetailsService) {
        this.customUserDetailsService = customUserDetailsService;
    }


    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable() //We don't need CSRF for this example
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated() // all request requires a logged in user
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login") //the URL on which the clients should post the login information
            .usernameParameter("username") //the username parameter in the queryString, default is 'username'
            .passwordParameter("password");
    }
}
```

Here, you config which urls are requested to login, and for the form, if you want to customise the login url, username and password fields.

Your main problem was that, you were not injecting the "UserDetailServiceImpl" in your class.

Hint here: Instead of using @Autowired, you can use the constructor like I did above, and the spring will inject for you, so you don't have to use the annotations.

This is a good approach after when you create unit tests and you can easily mock when constructing the class to test.

Comment: Thanks. @Autowired for customUserDetailsService could solve the problem also

Comment: Yes, @Roman I know that Autowired solved. I just wanted to highlight the good approach of using constructors instead of this annotation AND a little about the possibility of customising the login and the authorisation as you mentioned you are new to it...

Answer (score 2):

I used this answer and it worked for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42191609/1010619

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class AppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

public AppSecurityConfig(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
    super();
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) throws Exception {
    builder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    // @formatter:off
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/webjars/**", "/static/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/", "/index", "/home", "/register", "/user/confirmRegistration").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/loginCustom").permitAll().loginProcessingUrl("/doLogin")
            .and()
            .logout().permitAll().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            ;
    }// @formatter:on 

    public UserDetailsService getUserDetailsService() {
    return userDetailsService;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setUserDetailsService(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `UserDetailServiceImpl` in `SecurityConfig`, but you have not injected the `UserDetailServiceImpl` bean, which is causing that error. Just doing this is not enough:

`private UserDetailServiceImpl   customUserDetailsService;`

You need to inject `UserDetailServiceImpl` bean.